# How to get list of IP Addresses and Hostnames connected to local network in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

How to get list of IP Addresses and Hostnames connected to local network in React Native iOS. I see packages for android, but not iOS, does anyone know how I would go about this in Swift?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking (typically "local network" means connection to device itself, then its ip is always `127.0.0.1`, and the host name is always `localhost`), and on which tech stack (React Native is not related to Swift, even react native bridge is Obj-C).

Comment: my bad. When I say local network, I mean the network that the device is connected to wirelessly. I would want to see all the devices that are connected to the current Wifi network